# c++ calling a function using anonymous object results compiler error

Tags: c++, new-operator

Why following program fails in compilation.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Test
{
    public:
    void fun()
    {
        cout<<"fun() in Test\n";
    }
};
int main() {
    new Test()->fun();
    // your code goes here
    return 0;
}
```

Visit this link: http://ideone.com/qtCufW

It is allowed to call a member method using anonymous object in Java & C# but why not allowed in C++? 
Please help me.

Comment: What is the compiler error?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To fix the syntax error, parenthesise the new-expression

```
(new Test())->fun();
```

since the priorities of the `new` and `->` operators mean that yours is parsed as

```
new (Test()->fun());
```

which is ill-formed.

To fix the memory leak, stop using `new`. You're not writing Java or C# any more.

```
Test().fun();
```